# Simule una pantalla de 7 y 10 pulgadas con Chrome Element Inspector

Tags: android, google-chrome

Desarrollé una aplicación para Android usando WebView, pero Google está solicitando capturas de pantalla de una tableta de 7" y 10", pero no tengo una tableta. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer esta simulación usando el Inspector de Elementos de Chrome? Si es posible, ¿qué dimensiones debo usar?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Abre el inspector de elementos pulsando F12 en Crhome, luego en la barra de  menú superior del mismo (una estrechita) vete a la **izquierda** del todo y verás dos iconos, el segundo representa un movil delante de una tablet, y allí puedes simular tamaños distintos de dispositivos

Comment: Si no sabes los tamaños de esas tablets búscalos por la red, o dale al enlace "Edit" abajo del todo para que te muestre más a ver si alguno te cuadra

Comment: Hola masterguru, esto lo hice y solo aparecen las opciones que puse en el post. El problema es que no se que dimensiones debo poner para simular tablets de 7'' y 10''.

Comment: Yo tampoco :-)  Por eso te decia que los buscaras por la red (google por ejemplo), será un pim pam y no tendremos que hacerlo por ti :-)  Es decir, en la red saldran las especificaciones de esos modelos y sabrás si son de 7 o 10 pulgadas, pues en el chrome aparecen solo por pixeles

Comment: No creo que pueda explicar mi pregunta correctamente. Cuando usamos Inspeccionar elementos, solicita ancho y alto. ¿Cuáles serían exactamente esas dimensiones? Porque cuando hago una búsqueda en tabletas de 7'', me trae
18,70 cm de altura y
10,80 cm de ancho y cuando pongo estas dimensiones dista mucho del resultado que esperaba. ¿Cuál es el tamaño y la altura del dispositivo?

Comment: A ver, yo lo que haria seria comprobar las especificaciones del dispositivo a estudiar que te salga en esa lista... y si en sus especificaciones te dice que es de 7" entonces da igual los centimetros o pixeles que tambien digan que tiene, lo eliges y ya esta.

Comment: Por ejemplo, veo que el Sasmsung Galaxy S8+ es de 6,2 pulgadas, pues ese **no**.  Recuerda que puedes escoger más modelos si los que aparecen por defecto no son de ninguno de los dos tamaños que buscas. Para ello pulsa **Edit** en el mismo menú donde los eliges y te saldrán un buen puñado de ellos

Comment: O hazlo al reves, y busca "Tablet 7 pulgadas" en la red, y de los modelos que te salgan mira si estan en esa lista, y lo mismo para el de 10 pulgadas

Comment: Veo que **Nexus 7** es de 7 pulgadas, y **Nexus 10** de 10... en cuanto a las resoluciones, da igual, no te piden eso, y cada dispositivo podría ser distinto en eso.  Como no te lo han especificado usas esos y ya.